# On iPhone 4, off topic icons are a skewed

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, iphone

In the mobile theme, on iPhone 4, the icons for the sites offered to migrate to in the flag menu (off topic) are skewed. They are stretched vertically and squeezed horizontally. (I am on an iPhone now, hence no screenshot.)

Comment: Wow, so vote to close actually works if you go through the flag interface. The typical behavior applies that if you have close vote privileges, the flag is automatically converted into a close vote, and everything works peachykeen even on the mobile theme. I never even thought to try this... And since all of the infrastructure is there, I'm not sure why a "close" link wasn't added. It even knows how many votes I have left. (Also, yeah, I repro this.)

Comment: @Code Gray - space is at an absurd premium on mobile devices, so close wasn't made a separate menu link.  This is by-design.  Also, repro'd this bug fixing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this will go out with the next build.

Also, you can take a screenshot on an iPhone (at least an iPhone 4) by [holding the lock button and then pressing the home button](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/how-i-can-save-a-screenshot-of-an-iphone-application/3080#3080).

Comment: I know how to take a screenshot, but I couldn't upload it directly from the device.

Comment: @Moshe - ah, misunderstood that bit.